# Escape single/double quotes from Stripes action bean jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripes

I have a javascript function as below,

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("customer.name").value = "${actionBean.customer.name}";

.....

}
```

The value ${actionBean.customer.name} might have ' or "" quotes. How can I escape this from the javascript method?

For eg, the actionBean.customer.name dynamically becomes `"HI "I'M HOME""`

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) can do that for you. It has a method `escapeEcmaScript(String input)`.

Older versions in `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` contain a similar method `escapeJavaScript(String input)`.

I usually create a StringFunctions class, consisting of static functions, like wrapping the escapeEcmaScript function:

```
public static String escapeEcmaScript(String s) {
   return StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(s);
}
```

Include the `StringFunctions` class in a tag library descriptor:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.0">  

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>  
    <short-name>tlb</short-name>  
    <uri>http://www.trilobiet.nl/taglib/trlbt</uri>  

    <function>    
        <name>escapeEcmaScript</name>    
        <function-class>
            com.trilobiet.apollo.stripes.viewhelpers.StringFunctions
        </function-class>    
        <function-signature>    
            String escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)    
        </function-signature>  
    </function> 

    <!-- more functions -->

</taglib>
```

Include the tag lib descriptor in jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tlb" uri="/WEB-INF/taglib/tlb.tld" %>
```

(Of course you are free to use any short-name and taglib prefix that sound logical to you.)

And use like so:

```
${tlb:escapeEcmaScript(actionBean.customer.name)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it like this:

```
function check() {
    var customerName = (${actionBean.customer.name}).replace(/\"/g, '&quot;').replace(/\'/g, '&#39;');
    document.getElementById("customer.name").value = customerName;
    // continue function
}
```